# trigger not working as desired

Tags: sql-server

I want to change the modified date in the `Document` table when `Valid` is changed.

But modified date for all the documents with same id is changing even when the `Valid` column for only one of them is being changed.

So when I am changing the value of `Valid`, it is changing modified date for all the records with `ApplicationID=4`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Schema].[TGR_Document_ModifiedDate]
ON [Schema].[Document]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
    UPDATE [Schema].[Document]
    SET [ModifiedDate] = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM [Schema].[Document] 
    JOIN inserted i ON [Schema].[Document].[ApplicationID] = i.[ApplicationID] 
                    AND [Schema].[Document].[URI] = i.[URI] 
                    -- AND [AFI].[Document].[Valid] != i.[Valid]
```

And in my code I am just changing the value of `Valid` column and I am not at all changing `ModifiedDate`.

Comment: How about a sample of the update statement you are executing?

Comment: I think you should remove `INSERT` from the `AFTER` and just have it be an `UPDATE` trigger. Then compare the `inserted VALID` value to the `deleted VALID` value to see if it changed. Then update the `ModifiedDate` accordingly.

Comment: Why did you comment out the last line?   Seems like uncommenting it would fix the problem.  `-- [AFI].[Document].[Valid] != i.[Valid]`

Comment: @SeanLange -I have added the function which I am using to update in the question

Comment: @TabAlleman - doesnt help....I tried by uncommenting too

Comment: I love recursive triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have primary key on your table? If yes join to inserted table based on the primary key, not ApplicationID because it is not unique. Also I will suggest you to rewrite your trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Schema].[TGR_Document_ModifiedDate]
ON [Schema].[Document]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
IF (Update(Valid))
    UPDATE [Schema].[Document]
    SET [ModifiedDate] = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM [Schema].[Document] JOIN inserted i
    ON [Schema].[Document].[PrimaryKeyColumn] = i.[PrimaryKeyColumn] AND
        [Schema].[Document].[URI] = i.[URI] AND
```

So this trigger will check if you are modifying Valid column, it will Update the Modified Date column. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql)

I have tried this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Document (
ApplicationID INT NOT NULL, 
URI VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   
Valid INT, 
CreatedDate DATETIME, 
ModifiedDate DATETIME
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Document
(
    ApplicationID,
    URI,
    Valid,
    CreatedDate,
    ModifiedDate
)
VALUES
(   4,         -- ApplicationID - int
    'someuri',        -- URI - varchar(50)
    0,         -- Valid - int
    '2010-01-01', -- CreatedDate - datetime
    '2010-01-01'  -- ModifiedDate - datetime
)
,
(   4,         -- ApplicationID - int
    'somedifferenturi',        -- URI - varchar(50)
    1,         -- Valid - int
    '2010-01-02', -- CreatedDate - datetime
    '2010-01-02'  -- ModifiedDate - datetime
)
,
(   4,         -- ApplicationID - int
    'xyzuri',        -- URI - varchar(50)
    1,         -- Valid - int
    '2010-01-03', -- CreatedDate - datetime
    '2010-01-03'  -- ModifiedDate - datetime
)
,
(   5,         -- ApplicationID - int
    'uri',        -- URI - varchar(50)
    1,         -- Valid - int
    '2010-01-04', -- CreatedDate - datetime
    '2010-01-04'  -- ModifiedDate - datetime
)
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Document ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Document PRIMARY KEY(ApplicationID, URI)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.[TGR_Document_ModifiedDate]
ON dbo.[Document]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
IF (Update(Valid))
    UPDATE dbo.[Document]
    SET [ModifiedDate] = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM dbo.[Document] JOIN inserted i
    ON dbo.[Document].ApplicationID = i.ApplicationID AND
        dbo.[Document].[URI] = i.[URI] 
GO
UPDATE dbo.[Document] SET [Valid] = 1 WHERE ApplicationID =4 and Valid =0
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Document
```

The result for the select is following.

```
ApplicationID URI                                                Valid       CreatedDate             ModifiedDate
------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
4             somedifferenturi                                   1           2010-01-02 00:00:00.000 2010-01-02 00:00:00.000
4             someuri                                            1           2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 2017-10-02 23:37:09.443
4             xyzuri                                             1           2010-01-03 00:00:00.000 2010-01-03 00:00:00.000
5             uri                                                1           2010-01-04 00:00:00.000 2010-01-04 00:00:00.000
```

So only one row is updated.

Comment: ApplicationId and URI are the PK and ApplicationId is also FK

Comment: @Tina, can you please provide an example of your update query. Because if you are doing join based on the Primary Key it cant update several rows inside the trigger if you are just updating one.

Comment: I have added the function in my question which I am using to update

Comment: @Tina I was asking about query, not C# function.

Comment: UPDATE [Schema].[Document]
   SET [Valid] = 1
     
 WHERE ApplicationID =4 and Valid =0
GO

Comment: @Tina I have edited my answer based on your example.